# Error Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes

Tags: entity-framework

I am installing an application, following a developer tutorial, but when opening the web this error appears.

[image]

I don't have any knowledge in programming. I was reading all the posts related to the subject, but I can't solve my problem. I enclose the information I have.

## Web Error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.    Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.

## Exception Details:

> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException:
>   Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

## Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

## Stack Trace:

```
[AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.]
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +725
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +602
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +578
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +148
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
   VsomMonitoringTool.Mvc.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +69

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +546
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +171
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +255
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +347

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework"
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VsomMonitoringToolConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\VsomMonitoringDB;Initial Catalog=VsomMonitoringToolDB;User ID=sa;Password=M0n1t0r1ng" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="VsomMonitoringToolConnectionString_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\VsomMonitoringDB;Initial Catalog=VsomMonitoringToolDB;User ID=sa;Password=M0n1t0r1ng" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!--<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!--<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>-->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
    <contexts>
      <context type="VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess.VsomMonitoringToolContext, VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess.VsomMonitoringToolContext, VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess], [VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration, VsomMonitoringTool.DataAccess]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="VsomMonitoringToolConnectionString_DatabasePublish"/>
          </parameters>
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {465DCAD8-36C2-40E2-A742-9EC8BFCA8B9C}-->
```

---

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of handling with this problem, and more than one problems may causing this.

But you can try this approach, first `Add-Migration` and name it `Empty`.

And when your `Migration` is created, check if it contains any code in it, and if it has contains any extra or duplicate code, just delete it.

It should look like this:

```
public partial class Empty : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

And try it now.

Comment: Relevant MS link for the need of Empty migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the reply!
Sorry for my question, but I have no knowledge on the subject. 
How should I perform the Add-migration command?
According to what I was reading, I entered from Visual Studio> Package Manager Console and executed the command. In doing so he informs me of the following:

PM> add-migration.
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1.
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Empty
The running command stopped because the preference variable. "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\VsomMonitoringTool\http:\localhost\VsomMonitoringTool' because it does not exist.
PM>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfOmx.png)

What would be the correct way to open the application code and execute the command?